# Use the Method of Separation of Variables to Solve the PDE: $x u_x = u + y u_y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Use the method of separation of variables to solve the following
partial DEs:

$$x u_x = u + y u_y$$

my solution

$$ u_x= X' y $$
$$ u_y= Y' x $$
$$  u = xy$$

$$  xyX' = x y+xy Y' $$

stuck here

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have some misunderstanding in the notation between $X$ and $x$ or $Y$ and $y$! In fact, we have $X=X(x)$ and $Y=Y(y)$.

Take a look at the following steps

$$\eqalign{
  & x{u_x} = u + y{u_y}  \cr 
  & u = XY  \cr 
  & xX'Y = XY + yXY'  \cr 
  & {{xX'} \over X} = 1 + {{yY'} \over Y} = \mu   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  xX' - \mu X = 0 \hfill \cr 
  yY' - \left( {\mu  - 1} \right)Y = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} $$

Can you take it from here?